# Dynamic form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked a question early here today, and was led to using jQuery to solve a problem. I'm new to jQuery, but followed a reference and created the following code. It works in jsFiddle, but will not in my Firefox browser. jQuery is pointing to the right path, with the right file name. This is on my local server although I dont think that matters. I'd like to hide an unhide the input form based on the value selected from the dropdown Can anyone tell me why this will not work?

```
        <html>
    <style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    </style><!--end css-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#payment_type').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#nvendor').hide();
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h3>Select</h3>
    <select id="payment_type" name="payment_type">
       <option>Select a payment type...</option>
       <option value="nvendor">Add</option>
       <option value="PayPal">Update</option>
    </select>

    <form id="nvendor" class="hidden">
    Company: <input type="text" />
    Address Available: <input type="text" />
    Minimum Delivery Amount: <input type="text"/>
    Logo: <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#payment_type').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
         if(val == "nvendor")
           $('#nvendor').hide();
        else
           $('#nvendor').show();
     });
    })
</script>
```

and remove the class `.hidden` from the form

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfect. Do you know why this would work in jsFiddle but not outside of it?

Comment: js fiddle uses run js on either  ready or load .. and you havent that could be a reason

Comment: Thank you again. Can I last one more follow up question to this? If I'd like it to load with each form hidden instead of shown, how would I go about it?

Comment: @user1613223 yes of-course , you can do this but that time the form will already hidden than you can show the form on the condition   `if(val != "nvendor"){$('#nvendor').show();}`